# How to build package like pandas/numpy where pd/np is an object with all the functions

Tags: python, package

As per title, I am trying to build a python package myself, I am already familiar with writing python packages reading notes from https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages. These gave me an idea of how to write a bunch of object class/functions where I can import them.

What I want is to write a package like pandas and numpy, where I run import and they work as an "object", that is to say most/all the function is a dotted after the package.

E.g. after importing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

The `pd` and `np` would have all the functions and can be called with `pd.read_csv()` or `np.arange()`, and running `dir(pd)` and `dir(np)` would give me all the various functions available from them. I tried looking at the pandas src code to try an replicate their functionality. However, I could not do it. Maybe there is some parts of that I am missing or misunderstanding. Any help or point in the right direction to help me do this would be much appreciated.

In a more general example, I want to write a package and import it to have the functionalities dotted after it. E.g. `import pypack` and I can call `pypack.FUNCTION()` instead of having to import that function as such `from pypack.module import FUNCTION` and call `FUNCTION()` or instead of importing it as just a submodule.

I hope my question makes sense as I have no formal training in write software.

Comment: Can you post the module you've written, or a minimal example? What you've described seems like it would work. Hard to say what's wrong just from the description.

Comment: Just import all your functions into the base `__init__.py` and you'll have everything available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a module (package) called `my_library`.

```
.
├── main.py
└── my_library/
    └── __init__.py
```

`/my_library/__init__.py`

```
def foo(x):
    return x
```

In your `main.py` you can import `my_library`

```
import my_library

print(my_library.foo("Hello World"))
```

The directory with `__init__.py` will be your package and can be imported.

Now consider a even deeper example.

```
.
├── main.py
└── my_library/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── inner_module.py
```

`inner_module.py`

```
def bar(x):
    return x
```

In your `/my_library/__init__.py` you can add

```
from .inner_module import bar

def foo(x):
    return x
```

You can use `bar()` in your main as follows

```
import my_library

print(my_library.foo("Hello World"))
print(my_library.bar("Hello World"))
```